# What's the use of Presigned-expires?

Tags: http, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I found the following code snippet online. 
Not sure what the "presigned-expires" header in the request means. What'll happen if it is set to "false"?

```html
var req = new AWS.HttpRequest(endpoint);
req.method = 'POST';
req.path = path.join('/', esIndex, esType, '_bulk');
req.region = esDomain.region;
**req.headers['presigned-expires'] = false;**
req.headers.Host = endpoint;
```

Comment: Maybe nothing will happen.  It's not a header AWS will process in any case I can call to mind -- with rare exceptions, those start with `x-amz-`.  This seems likely to be something 3rd party.  Where did you find the snippet?

Comment: Found it here https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/696345/Use-the-Node-elasticsearch-client-with-A